Googlesheet formula
I'm trying to make this formula as one statement, what formula should I use, thanks.
=IF(AND($E2="Simple",$G2<=3),$M$2,$M$5)
=IF(AND($E2="Complex",$G2<=7),$M$3,$M$5)
=IF(AND($E2="Highly Technical",$G2<=20),$M$4,$M$5)

=IFS
  ($E2="Simple")*($G2<=3),$M$2,
  ($E2="Complex")*($G2<=7),$M$3,
  ($E2="Highly Technical")*($G2<=20),$M$4,
  1,$M$5)

Or
=IF(($E2="Simple")*($G2<=3), $M$2,
   IF(($E2="Complex")*($G2<=7), $M$3,
     IF(($E2="Highly Technical")*($G2<=20), $M$4 ,$M$5))) 

